# Guessing a password from a list of N passwords

Tags: probability

I want to know if my solution to the problem is correct:

I am given a list of n passwords to enter an account and only one will grant me access to it. I pick one and I test it. If it's incorrect, I delete it from and list and grab another one, iterating like this until i find the correct one. I have to calculate the probability in which I obtain the correct password in the 1st. 2nd. and 3rd. try.

I create the event Ck: obtain the correct password in k try.

P(C1) = 1/n

For C2, I should find it regarding that I have knowledge of not(C1) right? Then it would be:

P(C2 / not C1) = P(C2 and not C1)/P(not C1)

For C3, should I do the same thing?

Comment: Yes. Your method will work. For C3 you want P(C3 and not C2 and not C1)

Comment: You may wish to observe that the event $C_2$ necessitates $\mbox{not } C_1$, so $P(C_2 \mbox{ and not } C_1) = P(C_2)$.  Similarly for other constructions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!